# How is developed a strategy that allows you to stabilize any sorting algorithm for an Array with n Elements with "O(n) additional memory"?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, space-complexity, stability

For instance, Heap-Sort Algorithm is unstable or Quick Sort depends on the Implementation for stability. This stability must only be provided with O(n) additional memory, not the other strategies.

I have tried this question for the whole day, but I couldn't. Please Help!....

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a stable sort of a range `A` using an unstable sorting algorithm, you can:

- build a range `B` such that `B[i] = (A[i], i)`;
- sort `B` with the comparison function `B[i] < B[j] if (A[i] < A[j] or (A[i] == A[j] and i < j))`;
- write `B` back into `A` by just removing the second part (the `i`).

Comment: but here is Space Complexity O(n)?

Comment: @Cincan What is n?

Comment: n is the number of  Elements of an Array

Comment: @Cincan So yes, storing an additional n elements to build `B` satisfies your "O(n) additional memory" requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Associate to every array entry its initial index. Then when sorting, break ties by giving priority to the lowest index.

E.g., to stably sort

```
4 5 7 2 7 1 2 2
```

Augmented array:

```
4 5 7 2 7 1 2 2
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Sorted array (unused indexes omitted):

```
1 2 2 2 4 5 7 7
- 3 6 7 - - 2 4
```

Comment: but here is Space Complexity O(n)?